# How do I access (sha256) / sort (i128) a secondary/tertiary indices with cleos / curl?

Tags: multi-index, rpc, get-table, index

I'm trying to access either of our additional indices of the accountext table.  I'm able to access the 3rd index but I'm not sure how to sort it, the second index returns an empty table:

```
// this I get no rows from
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table dappservices ......2ke1.o4 accountext --index 2 --key-type sha256

// this returns the account names alphabetically, curious how I can sort this with lower/upper
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table dappservices ......2ke1.o4 accountext --index 3 --key-type i128 --limit 10000
```

Link to indices: https://github.com/liquidapps-io/zeus-sdk/blob/2b5148a92e601f5d6be54d60baf3feaf89010eca/boxes/groups/dapp-network/dapp-services/contracts/eos/dappservices/dappservices.cpp#L185

Get table row RPC link: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows-1

---

Get scope:

```
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get scope dappservices
{
  "rows": [{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "......2ke1.o4",
      "table": "accountext",
      "payer": "pnxdev111111",
      "count": 2692
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "......2ke1.o4",
      "table": "accountext..1",
      "payer": "pnxdev111111",
      "count": 1346
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "......2ke1.o4",
      "table": "stat",
      "payer": "dappservices",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "......2ke1.o4",
      "table": "statext",
      "payer": "dappservices",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "1111test1111",
      "table": "accounts",
      "payer": "instanttrack",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "13v3jeosdac1",
      "table": "accounts",
      "payer": "joneoswallet",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "13v3jeosdac1",
      "table": "staking",
      "payer": "13v3jeosdac1",
      "count": 2
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "1hellofadrug",
      "table": "accounts",
      "payer": "lovenotfight",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "1lovehalalll",
      "table": "accounts",
      "payer": "gqydcmrtgege",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "code": "dappservices",
      "scope": "1otthrhy1m3a",
      "table": "accounts",
      "payer": "newdexpocket",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "more": "1ozgoldmaple"
}
```

---

Says checksum256 is supported here: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/db-api

Comment: Have a similar question. I am actually just trying to be able to query a specific account name from dappservices / accountext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article answers this question in detail: https://cmichel.io/how-to-fetch-table-indexes-using-eosjs/

---

Fetching only the `ipfsservice1` services for the `helloworld12` account using the composite `by_account_service` key of the accountext table mentioned in the beginning (account << 64 | service) then requires:

- Little-endian hex encoding of `helloworld12`
- Little-endian hex encoding of the bounds for `ipfsservice1`
- Concatenating them in a way that matches the little-endian encoding of the `uint128_t`

---

```
const accountHexLE = getTableBoundsForName(`helloworld12`).lower_bound;
const serviceBounds = getTableBoundsForName(`ipfsservice1`);
const bounds = {
    lower_bound: `0x${serviceBounds.lower_bound}${accountHexLE}`,
    upper_bound: `0x${serviceBounds.upper_bound}${accountHexLE}`,
}
const rows = await fetchRows({
  code: `dappservices`,
  table: `accountext`,
  scope: `DAPP`,
  key_type: `i128`,
  index_position: 3,
  ...bounds,
});
```